# JTextfield - String split and intparse

Tags: java, string, swing, parsing, split

I am working on a turtle graphics project and I'm attempting to retrieve a user input from a jtextfield (commField) which should be like: ' forward 100 ' I've attempted to do a string split and intparse however when the program is run, even when a correct command is entered it will go to the message error dialogue. After a few hours of turning the cogs in my brain I'm struggling to figure out why and so am asking for any help. If more of my code is needed for an answer that is fine, perhaps I'm focusing on the wrong thing.

```
commField.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {


        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {


            else if(commField.getText().contains("forward")) {
                String cForward = commField.toString();
                String[] cForwardArray = cForward.split("\\s+");
                try {
                    int distance = Integer.parseInt(cForwardArray[1]);
                    graphicsPanel.forward(distance);

                } 
                catch (Exception ev) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(textArea, 
                            "Invaild or missing parameter, check the help section\n"
                            + "for more information on Commands");
                }
            }
            else if(commField.getText().contains("backward")) {
                String cBackward = commField.toString();
                String[] cBackwardArray = cBackward.split("\\s+");
                try {
                    int distance = Integer.parseInt(cBackwardArray[1]);
                    graphicsPanel.backward(distance);
                    graphicsPanel.repaint();
                } 
                catch (Exception ev) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(textArea, 
                            "Invaild or missing parameter, check the help section\n"
                            + "for more information on Commands");
                }
            }



        }
    });
```

Below is the full code block for those who want it:

```
commField.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {


        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            if(commField.getText().contains("penup")) {
                graphicsPanel.penUp();
            }
            else if(commField.getText().contains("pendown")) {
                graphicsPanel.penDown();
            }
            else if(commField.getText().contains("turnright")) {
                graphicsPanel.turnRight();
            }
            else if(commField.getText().contains("turnleft")) {
                graphicsPanel.turnLeft();
            }
            else if(commField.getText().contains("forward")) {
                String cForward = commField.toString();
                String[] cForwardArray = cForward.split("\\s+");
                try {
                    int distance = Integer.parseInt(cForwardArray[1]);
                    graphicsPanel.forward(distance);

                    System.out.println(commField);

                } 
                catch (Exception ev) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(textArea, 
                            "Invaild or missing parameter, check the help section\n"
                            + "for more information on Commands");
                }
            }
            else if(commField.getText().contains("backward")) {
                String cBackward = commField.toString();
                String[] cBackwardArray = cBackward.split("\\s+");
                try {
                    int distance = Integer.parseInt(cBackwardArray[1]);
                    graphicsPanel.backward(distance);
                    graphicsPanel.repaint();
                } 
                catch (Exception ev) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(textArea, 
                            "Invaild or missing parameter, check the help section\n"
                            + "for more information on Commands");
                }
            }

            else if(commField.getText().contains("black")) {
                graphicsPanel.black(Color.black);
            }
            else if(commField.getText().contains("green")) {
                graphicsPanel.green(Color.green);
            }
            else if(commField.getText().contains("red")) {
                graphicsPanel.red(Color.red);
            }
            else if(commField.getText().contains("reset")) {
                graphicsPanel.clear();
            }
            else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(textArea, "Invalid command, try again");
            }

            commField.setText("");
            graphicsPanel.repaint();


        }
    });
```

Comment: In my very limited testing, the concept of your code seems to be okay.  I would however, personally, use `String#startsWith` over `contains`.  You should put some more test conditions in your code (`if (cForwardArray.length > 1) {...}` and `System.out.println` statements to test what the variables actually are

Comment: added full code block also for those who requested

Comment: Thanks I'll try implement your suggestions

Comment: For debugging it is very helpful to print out the stacktrace of any exceptions that occur

Comment: Cool, I believe I actually had that in the code before but deleted it randomly in frustration. Cheers for reminding me! @Scary Wombat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Line of interest:

```
String cForward = commField.toString();
```

`JTextField.toString()` does not return the content of the `JTextField`.

I checked my java 8 sources and found the following:

```
public String toString() {
    return getClass().getName() + '[' + paramString() + ']';
}
```

However, the `toString()` method is intended to be a *debugging utility*. Unless its behavior is explicitly documented it is not recommended to rely on it programmatically.

For retrieving its text content, `JTextField` provides a separate method: [`JTextComponent#getText()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#getText--). The line should therefore be changed to:

```
String cForward = commField.getText();
```

Comment: Nice spot, missed that

Comment: Ah, interesting. So which method would be more appropriate? Thanks for answering.